# Beginner: Is there a better way than Chrome's Debugger to visualize Active & Outer Enviroments & variable scopes for debugging recursion call stacks?

Tags: javascript, debugging, recursion, callstack

```js
let add=function(x){
    if(x<=1){return 1;} 
    console.log(add(x-1)); 
    return (x+add(x-1));
};
console.log(add(5));
```

Chrome's visual guides are highlighting function calls & attaching values of dynamic variable names for the active enviroment. But has no visual aid to get know when the call stack exits the current enviroment & moves to the outer one and so on, it just updates the values of the variables in the dynamic dimension which is confusing if you don't follow it carefully.

Can you provide links to resources which allows a better visual way of seeing the call stack?

Comment: An old school pencil and paper are a great way to step through the process and learn what it does.  Just indent every time you go into a nested call, and shift back when returning out.

Comment: Thanks, that is what I am currently doing, also in web development, where is recursion applied in the logic, what are some of its use cases?

Comment: From my experience, recursion isn't used incredibly often.  When it is used, it is usually associated with a form of tree walking.  Where you either want to visit all paths of an object, or you want to find something at an unknown location or depth of some data structure.

Comment: Having said that, I can't currently recall a time that I have ever used recursion on the client side.

Comment: @Taplar if you comment `console.log(add(x-1)` its easy to write that down on paper, but if you use that code the indentation go outside the paper, because the number of call stacks for `console.log(add(x-1))` along with `return (x+add(x-1))` are multiplied not added, it really gets complicated pretty quickly.

Comment: The debugger shows the call stack. You should be able to see all the pending calls to the function.

Comment: You can click on each stack frame to see its local environment